# Scala/Spark : How to check if a dataframe contains a SPECIFIC list of columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I test if my DF contains a list of columns? I tried this:

```
finalDF.columns.contains(List("a", "b", "c"))
```

But I think contains method can only accept one column and not a list. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: A DF will always have columns. I think you mean a specific list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
List("a", "b", "c").forall(finalDF.columns.contains)
```

Or:

```
List("a", "b", "c").diff(finalDF.columns).isEmpty
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val colList = List("col1","col2","col3")

dataFrame.columns.filter(x => colList.contains(x))
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP wants.  It doesn't produce a Boolean result, and nor does it require matching all `colList` elements.  e.g. `Seq("a","b").toDF("col1").columns.filter(colList.contains)` would just result in `Array(col1)`.